# How to get dynamically the last value from a pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, pivot-table, formula

I have a pivot table like the one in the image:

[image: pivot table]

The table updates every month.
The question is: how can I dynamically get the last value of the table with a function, without VBA?
For example, in this case the last value is -32, just above the "Grand Total" value.
I'm considering to use the function "GETPIVOTDATA" but I don't know how to change the dynamic reference to the last value inserted. At the moment, the formula looks like this:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Count of DESIGNER]";$A$3;
"[Components_Drawings_Data].[DATE (Month)]";
"[Components_Drawings_Data].[DATE (Month)].&[giu]")
```

Comment: What is the intention of getting the last value? Is it because you want to retrieve the data of a specific month? In that case, you may want to use a VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to getting the last value is that I have a dashboard with some charts that give the overview of the data. I'd like to show in this dashboard how is the last value of that column that is not related to a specific month, but corresponds to the last time I've uploaded the table with new data

Comment: May it be more logic to calculate the value to your dashboard from the data instead of the pivot table?

Comment: The data are loaded as query from files and it's not so easy to calculate that value, I hope to get it more quickly from the pivot table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshot (below) / [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98XkbXWf-ZVgWNof5?e=zPePxo) refer.

Assuming:

- You can isolate the pivot table so that there are no populated cells
  beneath it (reasonable premise, given it's 'dynamic' and so variable
  re: # rows)
- You're not fixated upon using a PivotTable reference in formula
- You do not anticipate any row labels = 'Grand Total' (which would be unusual to say the least, however see alternative function below)
- Grand total for columns is displaying

Then the following will achieve what you have indicated:

> *...how can I dynamically get the last value of the table with a*
> *function, without VBA?*

[image: Screenshot for reference]

```
=OFFSET(INDEX($F$4:$F$100,MATCH("grand total", LOWER($F$5:$F$101),0)),0,1,1,1)
```

Note: the formula in cell L3 in above screenshot includes a wrapper for presentation  / ease of use only - i.e. 'Item' (col J) refers to the number of cells 'up' from the Grand Total at the very bottom of the pivot table... e.g. for item = 1 (one level up), 119 is returned (corresponding to 'woman'); for item = 2 (two levels up, 77 displays and so forth.

The corresponding label can be determined in a very similar fashion:

```
INDEX($F$4:$F$100,MATCH("grand total", LOWER($F$5:$F$101),0)-J3+1)
```

**Alternative/direct** (does not rely upon Grand Total for cols):

```
=OFFSET(F3,COUNTA(F3:F100)-2,1,1,1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What do you think are the differences with my proposal above?

Comment: You had a couple - central to your Q / attempt was the 'GETPIVOTDATA' - none of the proposed functions in my soln. included this due to its restrictive nature (as we can see given this Q).  You also referred to VB as a potential candidate/option - clearly I do not rely upon VB in any of the proposals I made.  Am I missing something re: an additional proposal (perhaps in a comment / elsewhere for instance?)  Let me know, ta.

Comment: Just before you answered me, I had proposed this solution:  'INDEX(B:B;MATCH("Grand Total";A:A;0)-1)'  so I was wondering what was the difference with your alternative

Comment: oic - I didn't realise you'd answered your own Q - so was only considering proposals you provided in Q.  Notwithstanding - I submitted 3 alternatives, one of which is clearly different as it does not rely upon "Grand Total" column being present.  (Besides that, using the entire column under index / match can be a bit more computationally intensive).  You'll often find several submissions along the same lines - when I'm composing a soln I cannot see other submissions until I'm done - and I rarely take an interest anyway - just move onto next open/unanswered question - per the filter I use...

Answer (score 1):

I elaborated this trick.
Suppose the column "Month" of the pivot table corresponds to column A, and the column "Delta" to column B.
I would use this formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B;MATCH("Grand Total";A:A;0)-1)
```

It could work.